# Python/list/file/loop/append

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I have to open a file and loop through the list.
Then I have to print the results and append/write certain lines to the same file.
I want to be able to run the code multiple times, but I do not want to append certain lines multiple times and I do not want to read appended lines. The question is - how to append/write only once and how to skip reading appended lines?
Here is the code:

```
kitty = 500

requests = []

file = open("loan_requests.txt", "r+")

requests = file.readlines()


for item in requests:

    flag = bool(int(item))
    if flag == False:
        break

    
    if  int(item) <= kitty and kitty > 0:
            kitty = kitty - int(item)
            loan = int(item)
            print(loan, "- Paid!")
            file.write("Request of {} paid in full.\n".format(loan))
        
    elif int(item) > kitty and kitty > 0:
             kitty = kitty - int(item)
             loan = int(item) + kitty
             print(int(item), "Request cannot be processed in full (Insufficient funds available). Amount paid:", loan)
             file.write("Request of {} could not be paid in full.Partial payment of {} made.\n".format(item, loan))

    elif int(item) > kitty and kitty <= 0:
             print("Request of", int(item), "is UNPAID!")
             file.write("Outstanding Request:{}\n".format(item))


file.close()



Tried with seek(); tell().
```

Comment: When you're appending the line that you don't want to repeat, set a flag variable. Then check that flag before writing it the next time.

Comment: Don't forget to write newlines after your messages.

Comment: The code that reads from the file expects the file to contain only numbers. But you're adding non-numeric lines when you write. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: You don't handle the case where `int(item) == kitty`, only `<` and `>`

Comment: I'm a complete newbie. Doing what I can. The code read numbers because the numbers are the only that I need. File contains only numbers. I'm adding the lines. That was a task.

Comment: Doing that in the last elif. <=

Comment: No you don't. It says `int(item) > kitty`.

Comment: You are right. All the lines that have write method.

Comment: I want to run multiple times and I want to print the results, but I don't want to append to text file more than once.

Answer (score 4):

Before writing to the file, check if the file already contains that line.

```
kitty = 500

requests = []

file = open("loan_requests.txt", "r+")

requests = file.readlines()

def write_new(file, line, requests):
    if line not in requests:
        file.write(line)

for item in requests:
    
    if int(item) < kitty and kitty > 0:
        kitty = kitty - int(item)
        loan = int(item)
        write_new(file, "Request of {} paid in full.\n".format(loan), requests)
        print(loan, "- Paid!")

    elif int(item) > kitty and kitty > 0:
        kitty = kitty - int(item)
        loan = int(item) + kitty
        write_new(file, "Request of {} could not be paid in full.Partial payment of {} made.\n".format(item, loan), requests)
        print(int(item), "request cannot be processed in full (Insufficient funds available). Amount paid:", loan)
            
    elif int(item) > kitty and kitty <= 0:
        write_new(file, "Outstanding Request:{}\n".format(item), requests)
        print("Request of", int(item), "is UNPAID!")

file.close()
```

Comment: My God! I learned more here in 5 minutes than through the whole course. Ok, do I have to use "def", because we still didn't come to that topic in the course that I'm going through.

Comment: def write_new(file, line, requests):
    if line not in requests:
        file.write(line)      THIS IS IT, BUT I NEED to be SIMPLIFIED.

Comment: How much simpler could it be?

Comment: if line not in requests:
        file.write(line)  - THIS IS IT. But without defining a method. Do I need to define a method before the loop block? Or I can check the if line is in requests inside the if else statemets?

Comment: YOu don't HAVE to. But since this needs to be done in so many places, it's better to define a function so you don't repeat the same condition every time.

Comment: Ok. Got the solution. Thank you, everyone. Especially to Barmar and kosciej16.  I'm new here so I don't know if I have to hit a like button or give a thumb up let me know.

Comment: kitty = 500
requests = []
file = open('loan_requests.txt')

for line in file:
    if line.strip().isdecimal():
        requests.append(int(line))
    
file.close()


with open('loan_requests.txt', 'a') as file:

    for request in requests:
    
        if request <= kitty:
            file.write('\nRequest of ' + str(request) + ' paid in full.')
            print(str(request) + ' - Paid!')............

Comment: Don't put code in comments. It's unreadable. And since Python depends on indentation, it's meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

Converting what Barmar suggests, let's start with helper function that will write or not depends on some flag:

```
SHOULD_WRITE = True
def maybe_write(file, message):
    if SHOULD_WRITE:
        file.write(message)
```

Now use that function instead of `file.write`:

```
# file.write("Request of {} paid in full.".format(loan))
maybe_write(file, f"Request of {loan} paid in full.")
```

Next time, change value of `SHOULD_WRITE = False`

**BONUS**:
Do you know python has such fancy syntax?

```
if 0 < kitty < int(item):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kitty = 500
requests = []
file = open('loan_requests.txt')

for line in file:
    if line.strip().isdecimal():
        requests.append(int(line))

file.close()


with open('loan_requests.txt', 'a') as file:

    for request in requests:

        if request <= kitty:
            file.write('\nRequest of ' + str(request) + ' paid in full.')
            print(str(request) + ' - Paid!')
            kitty -= request
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).